# Unable to locate json module required in code (program runs fine and module is used)

Tags: javascript, encryption, node-modules

one of the packages I am using happen to require a separate module that I want to look into:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
```

however when I try to look up in /node_modules/ where the modules are, I cannot find the crypto module... I searched accross the project and the module does not show up...

it looks like crypto is part of the main modules - how do I look inside the core code? where to look?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html. I googled "node crypto". i think nodejs.org holds a lot of info on repositories.

Comment: I've looked at the api, but what if I want to look at a specific function's code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `crypto` module is part of the standard library -- https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/crypto.html

Comment: How do I locate a function code (not the api) within my program that uses that module? for example I want to look at what the Decipher.update() call within the crypto module... I want to look at the code...